# spring websockets - is it possible to send a message to an offline user?

Tags: java, spring, websocket, spring-websocket

I have lots of users in my db.
I would like to be able to send a message to them via websockets even if they are not connected.
whenever i send a message to an offline user - i would like the messages to be enqueued for him until he connects and then all the messages are pushed to him.

something like that:

```
template.convertAndSendToUser(
                              "user123",
                               queue,
                               hello);
```

is that functionality even possible ?

Bear in mind I am using activeMQ as my message bus. (message broker). and the functionality i'm describing above is a standard in jms\message queues

EDIT: I created an app with activemq - when i send a message to an offline user the message is not enqueued, it is lost. any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What about storing messages to users that are not online in a database and when a user comes online look up if there are new messages in the databases.

Comment: Of course it's possible. It is in fact very simple. If you use a real Message Broker - like ActiveMQ or RabbitMQ - this works out of the box.

Comment: Boris - I created a simple application with activemq, whenever i'm sending a message to the offline user - the message is lost. can you reference me with a link or something?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [following](http://activemq.apache.org/manage-durable-subscribers.html):

Durable topic subscribers that are offline for a long period of time are usually not desired in the system. The reason for that is that broker needs to keep all the messages sent to those topics for the said subscribers. And this message piling can over time exhaust broker store limits for example and lead to the overall slowdown of the system.

You can always manually unsubscribe inactive durable subscriber using management tools like JConsole or Web Console, but clearly there's more that can be done to help manage systems that use durable subscribers (perhaps coming from environments that they don't control)
Staring with version 5.6 we introduced a few improvements in this area.

This is just an example but you can use the same tactic to tackle your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, my intention is to set an expiration time for all messages that are designated to specific users (1-2 days) so the exhaustion of the system resources is not an issue for me.

Comment: This is just an example but you can use the same tactic to tackle your issue